# LDAP Schemas and Tree Structure

Tags: inheritance, schema, ldap, hierarchical-data, openldap

How does LDAP define which enties may be places where in the tree ?

I noticed that OpenLDAP prevents me from placing a 'bootableDevice' below an 'organizationalUnit', but 'inetOrgPerson'. Logically that makes sense, but how is this enforced in the LDAP schemas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my understanding, in openLDAP evey nod is considered as a container for every nod. You noticed that OpenLDAP prevents you from placing a `bootableDevice` below an `organizationalUnit`. In fact if you look at `bootableDevice` in the schema file, you will see that it's an `AUXILIARY` class

```
objectClasses: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.12 NAME 'bootableDevice'
  DESC 'A device with boot parameters' SUP top AUXILIARY
  MAY ( bootFile $ bootParameter ) )
```

So you just can't instanciate an `AUXILIARY` class. You can instanciate a `computer` and add to it, an `AUXILIARY` class in order to beneficiate of `bootableDevice` attributs in `computer` objects.

Here is an example :

[image]

In other directories, like *Active-Directory* the tree is partly designed in the schema. Each class has a list of class that can contain it.

JP

Comment: The list is called Containment.  There be rules in them there trees.  That is why AD trees start with dc=something, as a dc object can contain pretty much everything that an old NT style domain could contain.

Comment: Strictly speaking "containment" is specific to MS AD and does not apply in this context.

Answer (score 0):

@JPBlanc gave the right answer for solving the original technical problem.

But for the records here's the answer for the main question:

> How does LDAP define which enties may be places where in the tree ?

The LDAPv3 specifications specifies [DIT Structure Rules and Name Forms](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4512#section-4.1.7) for defining tree structure and possible attributes for forming the RDN of an entry.
However OpenLDAP up to release 2.4.x does not implement this.